# Query database for Current Week Results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query my data for a date range based on current week of the year.

My query:

```
select * FROM Client_Transactions WHERE DATE(Client_Transactions.Timestamp) = WEEK(curdate()) ;
```

This returns no results. I also tried to sub curdate() for the actual week 25 and returned no results.

What i think this query means is select all columns from client transactions table where date = timestamp columns is = the current week of todays date

but clearly my logic is flawed.

How can i return this current weeks transactions based on timestamp?

sample data

```
ClientID, Timestamp, Transaction, 
'27','2018-06-27 10:25:17.000000',  '-1'
'25','2018-06-27 00:25:14.000000',  '-1'
'25','2018-06-27 00:25:14.000000',  '-1'
'25','2018-06-27 00:23:04.000000',  '-1'
```

Comment: Sample data would help to solve your issue

Comment: added sample data @MKhalidJunaid

Comment: I hope the linked answer will solve your issue

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid it did, thank you sir.